# Add image src to array in JavaScript without http-address

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, photo

**Problem:**

Trying to add image src to array without the website URL (http://).

**HTML code:**

```
<img src="images/pink.jpg" alt="Photo" class="pink">
```

**JS code:**

```
var photoArray  = [];
photoArray.push(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src);
alert(JSON.stringify(photoArray));
```

**Desired result:**

http:// and so on adds to the array but all I want the array to save is "images/pink.jpg" without any http:// beginning.

Comment: Please find the answers below and mark one as accepted if you are satisfied with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the browser expands the `src` property to the full URL. Use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) to the the attribute value instead of the expanded `src` property.

```
this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute('src')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.getAttribute('src')` instead. It will fetch exactly what you need.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var photoArray  = [];
photoArray.push(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute('src'));
alert(JSON.stringify(photoArray));
```

```html
<img src="images/pink.jpg" alt="Photo" class="pink">
```

Readup: [`.getAttribute()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)